# What does 'depending on rounding' exactly mean?

Tags: python, random, floating-point, rounding

About `random.uniform`, docstring says:

> Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding.

But I do not know what does 'depending on rounding' exactly mean.

Comment: Well underneath `random.uniform` in the docs it says `The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [current documentation for `random.uniform()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) reads:

> Return a random floating point number `N` such that `a <= N <= b` for `a <= b` and `b <= N <= a` for `b < a`.
>
> The end-point value `b` may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation `a + (b-a) * random()`.

Floating point arithmetic on computers is limited in precision and rounding errors caused by this imprecision may lead to `b` not being included in the full range of values used for the random value that `uniform()` returns.

[`random.random()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) returns a value between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive). There are values for `a` and `b` where a floating point calculation of the sum `a + (b-a) * (1.0 - epsilon/2)` does not equal `b`, but will be a minute amount *lower* than `b`, while for other combinations the sum *does* equal to `b`. `epsilon` is the minimum precision of a floating point number on your platform (see [`sys.float_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info)), and `1.0 - epsilon/2` the maximum value `random.random()` can return.

If you are interested in the *details* of *why* floating point arithmetic on computers is imprecise, I can recommend the following two articles:

- [The Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Example: `random.uniform(0, 5e-324)` includes the upper bound.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: ah, missed the `)`, read it as `]`. So the maximum value is `1.0 - epsilon` then?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The maximum value depends on the random generator.  It's usually not `1.0 - epsilon` with `epsilon` being the "epsilon" of the floating-point representation, but rather with an epsilon depending on how many bits the random number generator delivers.  This used to 48 bits some time ago, and the mantissa of double-precision numbers has 52 bits, so there's a factor of 16.  I'm investigating if this is still true.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: right, so not `1.0 - epsilon` exactly, but something close to that that depends on the resolution of the random number algorithm (Wichman-Hill, see [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l686)).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh, that's a very different algorithm than the one I had in mind. Yes, of course it depends on this algorithm, and I can't tell what the maximum value is at first glance. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I've added a note that I'm not sure what the exact maximum value is then, and leave it at that. It doesn't really matter for the general principle of the rounding error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, fair enough.  I figured out why I had a different algorithm in mind:  The one you linked is only used if you create an instance of `random.WichmannHill`, and you most certainly shouldn't.  Python uses a Mersenne Twister implemented in C.  Out of curiosity, I'm currently having a look at it. (+1 btw)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, wrong part of the source code, indeed. Oops.

Comment: Apparently, the current version of the Mersenne Twister uses 53 bits of resolution, so it can return all representable floating-point numbers in the range [0.5, 1.0), and the maximum is indeed the next representable FP number less than 1.0.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Just what I [had found](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23b21deef18f/Modules/_randommodule.c#l128) as well. That'd be `1.0 - sys.float_info.epsilon`.

Comment: Err, the predecessor of 1.0 is 1.0-epsilon/2

Comment: @aka.nice: Thanks, corrected. I can indeed get closer to `1.0` with `epsilon/2`.

Answer (score -1):

`rounding` is: if i round 3.45 upwards, i will get 4. but if i round it downwards, i will get 3. so in this case, the values of ranges coming from [ or ] will change depending on round